# An Iframe I need to refresh every 30 seconds (but not the whole page)

Tags: iframe, refresh

I have this bit of code

```
<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="240" height="80" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 src="irc_online.php">
</iframe>
```

I am adding this to a html widget I have on a sidebar, Is there a way I can make this refresh say every 30 seconds and not the rest of my page?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can put a meta refresh Tag in the irc_online.php

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

OR you can use Javascript with setInterval to refresh the src of the Source...

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 document.frames["frameNameHere"].location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: So did i do this wrong because it's not working (i can't seem to add a code box to this reply sorry)

[code]<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="240" height="20" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 src="irc_online.php">
</iframe>
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 document.frames["iframe"].location.reload();
}
</script>[/code]

Comment: Yes your <iframe> has not the name "iframe" but in your js code you set this.. so add <iframe name="iframe" ...></iframe> (the name attribute)

Comment: It's not working for me. This is what i have - 

<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 document.frames["iframe"].location.reload();
}
</script>
<iframe name="iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="240" height="20" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 src="irc_online.php">
</iframe>

Comment: This worked out perfect in my current project. I have a meta refresh that does a download when completed, and I needed another redirect a few seconds later, to send the member back to the page they were on. I changed the document.frames, too // window.parent.location = "URL STRING HERE" Thank ahmet2106

Comment: For some reason this only works for me (in chrome) if I use window.frames[...] as opposed to document.frames[...].
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames

Answer (score 17):

Let's assume that your iframe id= myIframe

here is the code:

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);
function reloadIFrame() {
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src="YOUR_PAGE_URL_HERE";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This actually should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

Okay... so i know that i'm answering to a decade question, but wanted to add something!
I wanted to add a google calendar with special iframe parameters. Problem is that the calendar didn't work without it.
30 seconds is a bit short for my use, so i changed that in my own file to 15 minutes
This worked for me.

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);
function reloadIFrame() {
 document.getElementById("calendar").src=calendar.src;
}
</script>

    <iframe id="calendar" src="[URL]" style="border-width:0" width=100% height=100% frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a simpler solution. In your destination page (irc_online.php) add an auto-refresh tag in the header.

Answer (score 0):

add "id='myiframe'" to the iframe, then use this script :

```
<script>

function f1()
{
 var x=document.getElementById("myiframe");
   x.src=x.src+Math.floor(random()%100000);
}

setInterval(f1,30*1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Where would i put this 
function f1() { var x=document.getElementById("myiframe"); x.src=x.src+Math.floor(random()%100000); } setInterval(f1,30*1000); it just show's on my page
Thanks