# Refresh an iframe automatically in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

I have a simple `iframe` that I want to refresh every 5 seconds, without clicking somewhere or doing something at all

```
 <iframe src="my-messages.php">
```

They want the user to click somewhere, I do not. I want this as an automatic process.

Comment: How much did you search? `Refresh an iframe automatically` in Google, top results ► https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146805/an-iframe-i-need-to-refresh-every-30-seconds-but-not-the-whole-page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975765/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-automatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123053/auto-refresh-iframe-html etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, though if the user is doing anything within the iframe they will lose their progress.

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector('iframe.reload').setAttribute('src', 'https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i5sso5fg/n1328/tluk');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<iframe class="reload" src="https://freesecure.timeanddate.com/clock/i5sso5fg/n1328/tluk" frameborder="0" width="57" height="18"></iframe>
```

Comment: I will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the refresh meta tag.  Just add this to the head section of `my-messages.php`...

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

Alternatively, add this to `my-messages.php` in order to do the same thing with Javscript...

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Is this going to refresh the page when accessed manually, ex. directly going to my-messages.php? Also thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: Yes, it will work on the page whether it's the top or in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to change the src of the iframe to "my-messages.php" again. This is a solution using JQuery to select the element.

`<iframe src="my-messages.php" id="frame">`

in your JS

```
var refreshMS = 10000;
var $frame = $('#frame');
var timeoutFunction = function(){
  $frame.attr("src", "");
  $frame.attr("src", "my-messages.php");
  setTimeout(timeoutFunction, refreshMS);
};
setTimeout(timeoutFunction, refreshMS);
```

This basically sets the src element every 10 seconds, causing the iframe to reload its contents.

Edit: As recommended, non-jquery version

```
var refreshMS = 10000;
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
var timeoutFunction = function(){
  frame.setAttribute("src", "");
  frame.setAttribute("src", "my-messages.php");
  setTimeout(timeoutFunction, refreshMS);
};
setTimeout(timeoutFunction, refreshMS);
```

Comment: You'll need to include JQuery on the page if you are not already using it.

Comment: You can do this without jQuery.  Use vanilla JS so they don't have to include a whole library for 1 thing.

Comment: Is this going to include JQuery: `<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>` ? Yes, I do have this script in my js folder.

Comment: I've gone ahead and provided an example that doesn't require JQuery. Sorry about that, me being lazy.

Comment: @DimitarBogdanov this may be an issue with Chrome not triggering the refresh unless the actual value changes. I've update the example to first set the src to empty and then back to the correct source. This should properly trigger the browser to refresh the iframe now.